# Querying for array whose values are in the specified array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Taking this document :

```
{
    "targets": [
        ['a', 'b'],
        ['a']
    ]
}
```

I would like to retrieve it with the following targets :

```
['a', 'b']
['a']
['a', 'b', 'c'] //because one target contains 'a' and 'b'
```

And not with this one :

```
['b'] //because non of the targets contains only 'b'
```

I tried with this query criteria but it doesn't work at all :

```
'targets': {
    '$elemMatch': {
        '$elemMatch': { '$in': target }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below find query.

```
db.collection.find({
    targets: {
      $elemMatch: {
        $not: {
            $elemMatch: {
                $nin: input array
            }
        }
    }
  }
});
```

`$elemMatch` with `$nin` selects all the documents with `targets` element have at least one array element with no value matching element in input array.

```
db.collection.find({
    targets: {
      $elemMatch: {
            $elemMatch: {
                $nin: input array
        }
    }
  }
});
```

input array - selection

```
['a', 'b'] - false
['a'] - false
['a', 'b', 'c'] - false
['b'] - true
```

`$not` to select the documents where `targets` element have array element which  is subset of input array.

```
db.collection.find({
    targets: {
      $elemMatch: {
        $not: {
            $elemMatch: {
                $nin: input array
            }
        }
    }
  }
});
```

input array - selection

```
['a', 'b'] - true
['a'] - true
['a', 'b', 'c'] - true
['b'] - false
```